# Typescript union of class methods has type never for an argument

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting

In a typescript project I'm working on, I have three separate classes A, B, and C, with a union type between them named X.

```
type X = A | B | C
```

A, B, and C all have a `.move()` method, and this method takes two parameters: `node` and `position`. `position` is of type `Position`, but `node` has a different union type depending on whether the method belongs to A, B, or C. Class A might take "left" or "right" for `node`, but class B might take "top" or "bottom" for `node`. When I have a variable `foo` of type X and attempt to call `.move()` on it, it says that "Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type never." Is there any typecasting or refactoring I can do to fix this issue?

EDIT: Here is some simplified code that displays this behavior. Ignore the error that foo is being used before it is assigned, the error pertaining the to argument is the important one here.

```
class A {
    move(node: "top" | "bottom") {

    }
}

class B {
    move(node: "left" | "right") {

    }
}

type X = A | B

let foo: X

foo.move("top")
```

Comment: Please provide reproducable example

Comment: On mobile so can't test. Do you just need to `let foo = new A(); foo.move("top")?` Or make the `move` methods static. It might be saying `never` because they're classes but you're not acting upon the instances. As far as refactoring, you could use an `enum` instead of union types and all of the `move()` methods would then take the same argument type as each other.